# Spring Web Socket + Docker rabbitMQ connection erro

Tags: docker, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-websocket, java-websocket

I'm trying to config Spring boot WebSocket and separate Stomp Broke.

Here is the configuration of the socket:

```
@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app")
        .enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic", "/queue")
        .setRelayHost("localhost")
        .setClientLogin("guest")
        .setClientPasscode("guest");
}
```

The docker-compose.yml I use to make rabbitMq broker:

```
version: '2'
services:
  rabbitmq-stomp:
    image: "jorgeacetozi/rabbitmq-stomp:3.6"
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
      - "61613:61613"
    environment:
     - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=test
     - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=password
```

When I run the application, it make's this error:

```
2018-07-23 11:13:59.734 ERROR 2958 --- [ent-scheduler-4] o.s.m.s.s.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler : Received ERROR {message=[Bad CONNECT], content-type=[text/plain], version=[1.0,1.1,1.2], content-length=[32]} session=_system_ text/plain payload=Access refused for user 'guest'
```

The rabiitMq terminal log shows this:

```
    rabbitmq-stomp_1  | =ERROR REPORT==== 23-Jul-2018::05:38:00 ===
    rabbitmq-stomp_1  | STOMP error frame sent:
    rabbitmq-stomp_1  | Message: "Bad CONNECT"
    rabbitmq-stomp_1  | Detail: "Access refused for user 'guest'\n"
    rabbitmq-stomp_1  | Server private detail: none
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to set the permission explicitly using [set_permissions](https://www.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmqctl.8.html#set_permissions) command

set_permissions [-p vhostpath] {user} {conf} {write} {read}

Do so in your docker_compose by using command tag:

```
version: '2'
services:
  rabbitmq-stomp:
    image: "jorgeacetozi/rabbitmq-stomp:3.6"
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
      - "61613:61613"
    environment:
     - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=test
     - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=password 
    command: rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p /myvhost guest ".*" ".*" ".*"
```